# Hive Function/Macro

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a Function/Macro in Hive. Instead of pushing it to UDF in java, I am trying to write within hql. Example below

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO testing(m string, mv double)
(
    'Testing',
    named_struct('m', m, 'value', mv)
);
```

It is getting following error -

```
  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: mismatched input ',' expecting ) near ''Testing'' in expression specification
```

I tried searching, but couldn't find good documentation on how to fix this.

Comment: Please provide query you are using

Comment: What do you need `'Testing',` for? leave `named_struct('m', m, 'value', mv)` and it should work just fine